# Using events or propositions as arguments

Tags: logic

I'm looking for ways to express sentences such as the following in logic (1st order or 2nd order if need be):

*"John knows that Bill loves Mary."*

*"Bill loves Mary"* is a predication (or an event), but it's not enough to write `Love(Bill,Mary)`, because I cannot use that as the argument of "know".

I want something like `Know(John,<Bill loves Mary>)`. I am very surprised that I couldn't find this sort of thing explained anywhere. What is the standard way to do this in formal logic?

Thanks!

Comment: It can be the argument of "know" if "know" is of the next higher order than "love".

Answer (score 0):

You might consider 2 predicates:

> Loves(*x,y*) mean *x* loves *y*
>
> KnowsLove(*x,y,z*) means *x* knows that *y* loves *z*

You would probably need at least the following axiom for your theory, whatever it may be:

> $\forall a,b,c:[\text{KnowsLove}(a,b,c)\implies \text{Love}(b,c)]$